# Best way to convert numeric array to CSV string?

Tags: java, csv, java-8

If I have a `String[]` (assume no commas) I can produce a CSV row simply.  E.g.,

```
String[] header = {"header0", "header1", "header2"};
String joined = String.join(",", header);
```

What's the nice way to do the equivalent with say `int[] vals01 = {0, 1, 2};`?  (I consider using `Arrays.toString` and slicing off the ends to be ugly.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done with the Streams API in a one-liner:

```
Arrays.stream(new int[] {0, 1, 2}).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(joining(","));
```

(assuming `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining`)

Answer (score 5):

Consider using the new (Java 8) [StringJoiner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html).

For a `String[]`:

```
String[] header = {"header0", "header1", "header2"};
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
Arrays.stream(header).forEach(joiner::add);
String joined = joiner.toString();
```

For the case of `int[]`:

```
int[] ints = {1, 2, 3};
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
Arrays.stream(ints).forEach(i -> joiner.add(Integer.toString(i)));
String joined = joiner.toString();
System.out.println(joined);
```